# $G$ is dense in $X^*$ in weak* sense if and only if $G$ is total set

Tags: functional-analysis, harmonic-analysis

I have some question on functional analysis.
Recently, I'm reading an article of Coifman and Weiss, "Extensions of hardy spaces and their use in analysis".

They proved some important theorem to me by using the following functional analysis fact without proof.

> **Exercise (Dunford&Schwartz, p.439, #41).** Let $X$ be a locally convex linear topological space and let $G$ be a linear subspace of $X^*$. Then $G$ is $X$-dense in $X^*$  if and only if $G$ is a total set of functionals on $X$.

In the case of Banach space, I can prove the one direction ($G$ is a total implies $G$ is dense in $X^*$ in the sense of weak* topology).

First, I proved that if $N$ is a subspace of $X^*$, then $(^\bot N)^\bot = \overline{N}^*$, where $-^*$ denotes the weak* closure.  Here I follow Rudin's notation. So the result of one direction is proved one takes $^\bot N=\{0\}$.

But I fail to prove its reverse direction and I cannot extend to the locally convex linear topological space case.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The dual of $(X^*,weak^*)$ is $X$. So the result is immediate from Hahn-Banach.

Comment: Share your proof of the direction you can show for Banach spaces,  so we can see how it can (or cannot) be extended to locally convex spaces.

Comment: @Aweygan I add proof of one direction. It seems like it does not depend on some structure of Banach space.

Comment: @WillKwon I fortunately have a copy of Rudin's book handy :)  After reading that section, it looks like your proof still works for general locally convex spaces.

Comment: @Aweygan Thanks for your reply!

Comment: @WillKwon No problem! always glad to help a fellow student of functional analysis

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume $G$ is not total. Then there is some $x\in X$ ($x\neq 0$) such that $x^*(x)=0$ for all $x^*\in G$.  Thus the set $\{x^*\in X^*:x^*(x)\neq 0 \}$ is a weak$^*$ open set which is disjoint from $G$, so $G$ is not weak$^*$ dense.