# If $N\subset X^*$, then $({^\perp N})^\perp = \overline{N}^{w*}$

Tags: functional-analysis, dual-spaces, weak-topology

I was trying to prove the following fact:

Suppose that $X$ is a Banach space and $N\subset X^*$ a linear subspace. Then $(^\perp N)^\perp = \overline{N}^{w*}$, where the closure is in the weak* topology.

I found this statement here

[$G$ is dense in $X^*$ in weak* sense if and only if $G$ is total set](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1859334/g-is-dense-in-x-in-weak-sense-if-and-only-if-g-is-total-set)

where the author of the post references to an exercise written (without solution) in the book of Dunford and Schwartz.

Answer (score 2):

$(^{\perp}N)^{\perp}$ is $w^{\ast}$-closed, so $\overline{N}^{w^{\ast}}\subseteq(^{\perp}N)^{\perp}$.

For the other direction, if $x^{\ast}\in X^{\ast}-\overline{N}^{w^{\ast}}$, then an application of Hahn-Banach Theorem gives an $x\in X$ such that $\left<x,x^{\ast}\right>=1$ and $\overline{N}^{w^{\ast}}\subseteq\ker(Qx)$, where $Qx$ is the canonical induced element in $X^{\ast\ast}$. Since $x\in{^{\perp}N}$, then $x^{\ast}\notin(^{\perp}N)^{\perp}$.

**Edit:**

If we endow $X^{\ast}$ with $w^{\ast}$ topology $(X^{\ast},w^{\ast})$, this is not the norm topology, and the continuous maps on $(X^{\ast},w^{\ast})$ are those $Q(X)$, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3438312/linear-functional-on-x-which-is-weak-continuous).

Comment: Actually, could you please be more precise of what you mean by "an application of the Hahn-Banach theorem"? Because I can get $x^{**}\in X^{**}$ separating the two sets, but not $x^{**}\in X$.

Comment: Actually you can re-examine the proof of the Hahn-Banach separation theorem in $X^{\ast}$ to get the assertion, I will try to refer you a reference of that exact statement.

Comment: If you were to give me a better reference that would be great, because a simple application of Hahn-Banach only gives an element into the bi-dual space.

Comment: See the edited post, something is very important.

Comment: Now it is all clear, thanks a lot!!